# How can i get the edited proxy from RequestFactoryEditorDriver

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I can't figure out how to update my celltable after changes have been made using an editor. If I could get the edited proxy then I can use the dataprovider to update my celltable.

```
public void saveCampaign() {
  driver.flush();
  // the problem. proxy at this point should have the new values?....
  context.persist().using(proxy).fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void response) {
      showListView();
    }
  });
}
```

The proxy in .using(proxy) does not contain the changes made on the editor. However the persist method on the server gets the updated values. If I reload the data from the server I get the correct values to the celltable.

```
public void editCampaign(CampaignProxy proxy) {
  this.proxy = proxy;
  if (proxy != null) {
    context = AEHOME.requestFactory.campaignRequest();
    showEditView();
  }
}

private void showEditView() {
  driver.initialize(eventBus, AEHOME.requestFactory, editView);
  driver.edit(proxy, context);
  deckPanel.showWidget(deckPanel.getWidgetIndex(editView));
}
```

Proxy is set in the list view: configurationPageView.proxy = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change how the request is built by doing the following:

```
private void showEditView() {
  driver.initialize(eventBus, AEHOME.requestFactory, editView);
  driver.edit(proxy, context);
  // Set up method invocation and callback in advance
  context.persist().using(proxy).to(new Receiver<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void response) {
      showListView();
    }
  }););
  deckPanel.showWidget(deckPanel.getWidgetIndex(editView));
}

public void saveCampaign() {
  driver.flush().fire();
}
```

In GWT 2.4 it will be possible to keep your current code organization and use `RequestContext.append()`:

```
public void saveCampaign() {
  // Returns the context passed to edit()
  RequestContext ctx = driver.flush();
  // append() is generic and returns the type returned by myProxyContext();
  ctx.append(requestFactory.myProxyContext()).persist().using(proxy).fire(....);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response. I have a better understanding now. I'm still unable to get a reference to the editProxy to update my celltable with. I tried to return the new proxy from the persist method but that breaks the ReqeustFactory interface. I was expecting the celltable to automatically update. What is a good way to update the celltable after an edit as occurred in a proxy the celltable is displaying? onSuccess(Void response) {
        proxy.getAdTitle(); // proxy at this point has old values
        showListView();
      }

Comment: The most robust way to update the UI is to have your UI element listening for `EntityProxyChange` events off of an shared `EventBus`.  When the UI element receives a notification that an entity that it cares about has been updated, it should make its own `RequestFactory.find()` (since the event only contains an id) to retrieve the data that it requires. This decoupling can help to decrease the amount of cross-wiring between concerns in your code. In GWT 2.4, using `RequestBatcher.get().find()` will make this more efficient.